# How to send JSON back with JAVA?

Tags: java, json

I am having problems [using Gzip compression and JQuery together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706412/use-gzip-json-responses-and-jquery). It seems that it may be caused by the way I am sending JSON responses in my Struts Actions. I use the next code to send my JSON objects back.

```
public ActionForward get(ActionMapping mapping,
    ActionForm     form,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) {
       JSONObject json = // Do some logic here
       RequestUtils.populateWithJSON(response, json);
       return null;             
}

public static void populateWithJSON(HttpServletResponse response,JSONObject json) {
    if(json!=null) {
        response.setContentType("text/x-json;charset=UTF-8");           
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        try {
             response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException("IOException in populateWithJSON", e);
        }                               
    }
 }
```

Is there a better way of sending JSON in a Java web application?

Comment: I used response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); instead of response.setContentType("text/x-json;charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of

```
try {
       response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
       throw new ApplicationException("IOException in populateWithJSON", e);
}
```

try this

```
try {
        json.write(response.getWriter());
} catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException("IOException in populateWithJSON", e);
}
```

because this will avoid creating a string and the JSONObject will directly write the bytes to the Writer object

Comment: I'm working on something similar, which library is used to import json.write()?

Answer (score 5):

In our project we are doing pretty much the same except that we use application/json as the content type.

Wikipedia says that the [official Internet media type for JSON is application/json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think using JAX-RS is the best way to deal with data binding, be that XML or JSON. [Jersey](http://jersey.dev.java.net) is a good JAX-RS implementation (RestEasy is good too), and has good support. That way you can use real objects, no need to use Json.org libs proprietary classes.

Answer (score 0):

response.getWriter().**write**(json.toString());

change to:
response.getWriter().**print**(json.toString());

Comment: uhm, just to write something?